# Designing ALU Control block for single cycle MIPS

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, alu

Hope this isn't off topic for Stack Overflow.

I was learning about MIPS and I've gotten stuck at this step. This is the truth table for the ALU Control Block.

[image: Img]

Now this is the first time I'm coming across such a complicated truth table with don't care conditions in their inputs. If I expand the don't cares to 1s and 0s (and keeping everything else the same) then the table will become enormous because of various permutations for each X.

Is there any other easy way to simplify such tables for the purpose of simplification of circuits or are calculated in computers?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the psuedo-code for what the table is telling you:

```
if ALUop == 00b then operation = 010b 
else if ALUop0 == 1 then operation = 110b 
else operation is a function of F3,F2,F1,F0
```

You can use a [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map#Don.27t_cares) to minimize logic functions including don't care values. This will enable you to specify a minimal logic equation to select `operation` based on the values of `F3,F2,F1,F0`.